# set data from database and push it into "List" in Model class

Tags: database, list, model, combobox

I've been probably missing something or maybe doesn't understand how it works, but I'm trying to get data from database, push it into model class (into property) - list, and get values from list into ComboBox. What I made so far is:

Created DBConnection class which gets "connstring", executes sp, read data from database. I also created model which has one property "Department" that I would like to use to push values into ComboBox by using comboBox1.Items.Add()...

What am I missing? Why do I get casting error?

Model class:

```
namespace AddRequester
{
    public class ListDepartment
    {
        public List<string> Department { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DBConnection class:

```
namespace AddRequester
{
    public class DBConnection
    {
        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConfig"].ToString();
        public void listDepartment()
        {
            SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(conn);
            try
            {
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("ListDepartment", sql);
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sql.Open();
                ListDepartment departs = new ListDepartment();
                using (var dr = comm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        departs.Department = dr["Description"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { 
                //add output
            }
            sql.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Also what is the best way to get values from model into combobox?

Answer (score 0):

since nobody knew hot to do it, I've done it in a different way. I'm sharing code so others can use it if they get stuck with same problem.

So, I have modified code for DBConnection class and completely remove "model" ListDepartment class,

```
namespace AddRequester
{
    public class DBConnection
    {

        public List<string> listDepartment()
        {
            string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConfig"].ToString();
            SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(conn);
            List<string> departments = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("ListDepartment", sql);
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sql.Open();
                using (var dr = comm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                       var dep = dr["Description"].ToString();
                       departments.Add(dep);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            sql.Close();
            return departments;
        }
    }
}
```

I have added into Form1.cs

```
namespace AddRequester
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
            foreach (var deps in db.listDepartment())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(deps);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Finally, when I start application, and use combobox1, I get list of items from database.
cheers.